# Getting the string of an external link to another worksheet's cell?

Tags: vba, excel

The Worksheet object has a *Paste* method that has a parameter named *Link*. If this is set to be True a link is created into the Range selected by the cursor, to the Range currently on the clipboard (aka. that is sorrounded by marching ants). The resulting link in the cells will look like:

```
='\\DES001\Home folder\[the book.xlsx]sheet1'!$A$1
```

Now, is there a function that returns this string itself? (without the = sign)

Answer (score 0):

You can read it into a string.  Not sure how you have your link build with address and subaddress but you can do something like this.

My link is in cell C3. You will have to change it to whatever cell your link is in.

```
Private Sub CommandButton36_Click()
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")

    Dim s As String
    s = ws.Range("C3").Hyperlinks(1).Address
    'or
    s = ws.Range("C3").Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress
    MsgBox (s)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used sample Range A2. Modify according to your requirement

```
 Sub TestLink()
        Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim sString  As String

        Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")

       ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Range("A2"), _
                                           Address:="http:\\www.google.com\", _
                                           SubAddress:="google.com", _
                                           TextToDisplay:="Link"


        sString = ws.Range("A2").Value
        MsgBox sString

    End Sub
```